# Unable to install np_utils using conda

Tags: python, conda

While installing 'np_utils' through conda, using the below command:

`conda install -c auto np_utils`

The below error appears:

`RemoveError: 'pyopenssl' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.`

`RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.`

Also tried installing 'setuptools' and 'pyopenssl' using conda, which results in the same error.
Moreover, 'setuptools' and 'pyopenssl' does not exist, which has been observed by using `conda list`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with some different packages, ie. "conda install bottleneck". Doing it in git bash cmd instead of anaconda prompt doesn't work either (on Windows 10).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have removed conda completely and deleted the pkgs directory, then followed by the fresh install. Not a valid solution tough. A longer procedure, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this before the installation

```py
conda update --force conda
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running Anaconda Prompt as an Administrator, then run this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge np_utils
```

It worked for me.

Here is the source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/np_utils